# linux shell script printf number format color

Tags: linux, shell, colors, numbers, printf

Ahead, Sorry for my english sentence. ( I am weak at English )

Here is a source.
I wanna color the ${test} in %d %f format.
But I get an error. Invalid number.

I wanna maintain %d %f format ( for comma and point ) and also want the color.
Please, know the way.

source

```
#!/bin/sh
warning_color=$(tput setaf 4) # blue
end_color=$(tput sgr0)

test="30000"
result="30000"
if [[ ${test} -gt 20000 ]]
then
  test="${warning_color}${test}${end_color}"
fi
printf "%'10d%'10d\n" "${test}" "${result}"

test="30000.13"
result="30000.13"
if [[ ${test%%.*} -gt 20000 ]]
then
  test="${warning_color}${test}${end_color}"
fi
printf "%'10.2f%'10.2f\n" "${test}" "${result}"
```

error ( 30000 and 30000.13 color is blue in error message )

```
a.sh: line 7: printf: 30000: invalid number
     0a.sh: line 11: printf: 30000.13: invalid number
  0.00
```

Comment: Can you please show your expected ouput, not just the error you're getting?

Comment: I just wanted colored number. Now I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the colours to the format strings, otherwise the numbers are no longer as into or float when you add the color codes to The variables

Ex.

```
$ blue=$(tput setaf 4)
$ end=$(tput sgr0)
$ val1=3000
$ val2=3000.11
$ printf "$blue %10d $end\n" $val1
        3000
$ printf "$blue %10.2f $end\n" $val2
     3000.11
```